# Odd closure behavior

Tags: javascript, jquery, closures

For some reason, the following bit of code isn't behaving as I would anticipate -- likely due to a misunderstanding on my end as to how it should behave.

```
var contentPane = widget.children("div.content").first();

var success = function (content) {
    return function (data, successCode, httpRequest) {
        content.innerHTML = data;
    };
}(contentPane);
```

I've attached my debugger (well, Firebug anyway) and it looks like 'content' on the line `content.innerHTML = data;` is the Window object, when I should be the result of `var contentPane = widget.children("div.content").first();`, correct?

Note that if I set a breakpoint before the function, contentPane is indeed set to what I would expect (a jQuery object matching `div.content`). Whats going on here, what am I missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is what they added [`$.proxy()`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.proxy/) for in 1.4 :), like this:

```
var contentPane = widget.children("div.content").first();

var success = $.proxy(function (data, successCode, httpRequest) {
                       this.innerHTML = data;
              }, contentPane);
```

This just makes the closure declaration for the common case like you have much shorter, [`$.proxy(function, whatThisIs)`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.proxy/).

---

For the "what's wrong?" part...nothing, are you sure you're checking the right variable?  `this` refers to `window` inside your function, but `content` is the jQuery object you want...you can see a quick test here: http://jsfiddle.net/vhcde/

Comment: @downvoter - it helps to say *what* is incorrect, so it actually helps someone.

Answer (score 1):

The problem may likely be your selector.  The following works fine when run on this page

```
var contentPane = $("#header")[0];

var success = (function (content) {
    console.info(content);
    return function (data, successCode, httpRequest) {
        console.warn(content);
        content.innerHTML = data;
    };
})(contentPane); 

success("ohai");
```

* I've added parenthesis around the function definition for added clarity.